# Azure Data Factory Dataset with @ in column name

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a Dataset coming from a Rest webservice having an @ in the column name:
Like:
    `{
        data[{
                 @id : 1,
                 @value : "a"
            }, {
                 @id : 2,
                 @value : "b"
            }
        ]
    }`

i want to use it in a foreach and access the specific column:
in the foreach i get the output like `@activity('Lookup').output.value`

in the foreach there is a stored procedure
as parameter input i tried to get the column: i tried `@item().@value` but got the error "the string character '@' at position 'xx' is not expected".

is there a way to escape the @ in the column name? or can i rename the column?

Thank you very much

edit: 
here is the JSON from the ADF pipeline:

```
{
"name": "pipeline3",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Lookup1",
            "type": "Lookup",
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "HttpSource",
                    "httpRequestTimeout": "00:01:40"
                },
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "HttpFile1",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "firstRowOnly": false
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "ForEach2",
            "type": "ForEach",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Lookup1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.value",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Stored Procedure12",
                        "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
                        "policy": {
                            "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                            "retry": 0,
                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "storedProcedureName": "[dbo].[testnv]",
                            "storedProcedureParameters": {
                                "d": {
                                    "value": {
                                        "value": "@item().@accno",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    },
                                    "type": "String"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "linkedServiceName": {
                            "referenceName": "AzureSqlDatabase1",
                            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
```

}

Comment: What language are you using for you foreach? What stored procedure are you talking about?

Comment: i added the adf json. i use the adf expression language and the storedprocedure is just a dummy which takes one parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try "@item()['@accno']" for @item().@accno
Also replied in MSDN.